# Is there a list of VSS Treeview Icons?

Tags: tfs, azure-devops, visual-sourcesafe

Refering to the Treeview control for VSTS / TFS:

[https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/vsts/extend/develop/ui-controls/treeviewo ]

Is there a list of icons for us to choose?

```
icon: "icon icon-people"
```

or is there a way to load our own images.

Example:

```
icon: "./images/sample.png"
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, `icon-people`, `icon-pause` such as this kind are all **build-in** icons of TFS/VSTS extension. You could find them in your TFS/VSTS page and you could also directly call them in your custom extension.

Unfortunately, we don't have the official full list of icons. You could refer this [tutorial](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/vsts/extend/develop/ui-controls/menubaro) which contain some commonly used.

Load your own images is also support, the format just like you described above `icon: "xx/images/sample.png"`, here is a extension which use his own icon in menu bar, take a look at the [source code](https://github.com/konradsikorski/VSS.Extension.ChangeState/blob/master/src/changeStatusMenu.js) if you are interested in.

Comment: Moreover, if you want to use a  build-in icon and don't the accurately name of it. You could add the screenshot of it here, I will help you find the name.

Comment: Thanks Patrick for your reply. The icons in the [tutorial](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/vsts/extend/develop/ui-controls/menubaro) works. However, I'm unable to load my own images in the treeview.

See this [image](https://ibb.co/gWjZZG) of my code snippet. Only the icon-info is able to display the built-in images.

Comment: Just to add that I have included the images in vss-extensions.json as well.


`{
                "path": "images/folder.png", "addressable": true
            },
            {
                "path": "images/logo.png", "addressable": true
            },
            {
                "path": "images/plan.png", "addressable": true
            },
            {
                "path": "images/test.png", "addressable": true
            }`

Comment: @KahWaiLee Have you tried `icon: "icon images/folder.png"` this format in your code. And what's the detail pixels of your icon image. Must be small than default (128x128 pixels) of type BMP, GIF, EXIF, JPG, PNG and TIFF).

Comment: `icon: "icon images/folder.png" doesn't work. Anyways, I think the tree view is fine. I am facing another issue with the use of the VSTS treeview. I think I shall use another treeview instead. I marked your answer as the best response. :D